# What is the size of buffer associated with file when file is open with library function fopen()?

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, size, buffer

When a FILE is open with a fopen() a buffer is associated with it to write and read from the files this is done to avoid direct access of disk because it is costly.

I found on some online tutorials saying when we load a file into main memory (RAM) four stuffs get created stdin, stdout, stderror, Buffer and this buffer is used to read/write in the file, I am curious to know how much size is allocated by OS for this buffer does it depend on OS architecture? Is there any possibility to know its size?

Answer (score 5):

The default buffer size is macro constant `BUFSIZ` defined in `stdio.h`. The value is implementation dependent. You may use `setvbuf()` to change the buffering mode (Full/Line/No buffering) and buffer size.

Reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io